# What quest should I start to do Cursed Captives?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I want to get the "Cursed Captives" achievement, located in Cursed Hold. For this I'm returning to the normal difficulty with my character. What quest should I start that will get me as close as possible to the Cursed Hold?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do the quest The Imprisoned Angel, if you select the second option of the quest ( The Cursed Hold ) you can take the waypoint to to Hall of Agony level 2, exit to Highlands Crossing then to The Cursed Hold.